# Dynamicaly build linq to objects where expression

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Experts!

Got stuck with one (might be simple for someone) question.

I have an object:

```
   public class DataItem {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<String, Object> Values { get; set; }
   }
```

What i need to do is to build linq **.Where** dynamicaly from "Caml like" Xml. On Xml parsing i use switch for conditions to build linq predicates:

```
switch (Type) {
  case CriteriaType.Contains:
  break;
  case CriteriaType.Eq:
  break;
...
```

and using **PredicateBuilder** (from [C# 5.0/4.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)) to combine Expressions, but thing is i have no idea how to build expression predicate e.g. GreaterOrEqual.
Idea was to have function like:

```
public Expression<Func<DataItem, bool>> Geq<T>(String field, Object value)
```

Where **DataItem** is object we're going to query, **T** is Dictionary item value type, parameters **field** is key from **DataItem.Values** dictionary and **value** is value of this key.

But here is the catch:

- Since we're operating with objects they should be converted to type
  .
- And since we're not sure that DataItem.Values collection has key
  we need, expression should be build as linq equivalent of

  p => p.Values.ContainsKey(field) && p.Values[**field**] >= **value**

If someone could help me with this, that would be just awesome.

Also i would be very appreciated for some nice tutorials & links with *"easy to understand"* examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Silverlay I think what you are looking for is Dynamic LINQ.  This is a library provided by the LINQ team itself.

What you need to do is use string expressions instead as shown in this blog -
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: That's a quite close solution i can live with :) made quite a big wrapper for this, but since it's official and supported solution it's more then prefect for me. Thanks a lot, mate.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just add .Where clauses to the query like this?

```
// query
var query = from d in dataItems select d;

switch (expressionType) {
    case CriteriaType.Contains:
        query = query.Where(d => d.Values.ContainsKey(field));
    break;
    case CriteriaType.Eq:
        query = query.Where(d => d.Values[field] >= value);
    break;
```

Also, I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "Since we're operating with objects they should be converted to type", but maybe you could redefine your DataItem class to be generic:

```
public class DataItem<T> {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, T> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That won't help since dictionary contain numerous objects of different types. And you basicaly gave em all a single type.